# foundation4 can't enter text into input type="text"

Tags: html, css, forms, zurb-foundation, internet-explorer-11

I have a website based on Zurb Foundation 4. Recently I noticed that in IE11 and IE10 on Win8.1 Desktop, users cannot fill in form field (input type=text). Through testing I found that if the Foundation CSS is excluded it works. Example:

Cannot enter text

http://www.shedshop.net.nz/contact-us

Can enter text

http://www.shedshop.net.nz/contact-us?nofoundation=1

This is independent of the foundation css being compressed or not.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the input field was styled in a way that would allow 0px height for the text, therefore whatever you typed in was not visible.